# Multiclassification Error: NotFittedError: This MultiLabelBinarizer instance is not fitted yet

Tags: machine-learning, python, multiclass-classification, data-science-model, multilabel-classification

After picking the model, when I try to use it, I am getting error -

> "NotFittedError: This MultiLabelBinarizer instance is not fitted yet.
>   Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator."

```
X = <training_data>
y = <training_labels>

# Perform multi-label classification on class labels.
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
multilabel_y = mlb.fit_transform(y)

p = Pipeline([
('vect', CountVectorizer(min_df=min_df, ngram_range=ngram_range)),
('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(clf))
])

# Use multilabel classes to fit the pipeline.
p.fit(X, multilabel_y)
```

Comment: Could you give an example data of X and Y in order to make the code reproducible?

Comment: sure, sorry. For example, X = "How to join amazon company ". Y = ["Career Advice", "Fresher "]. @CarlosMougan

Comment: Try to make the question reproducible, so if we copy paste we can debug the same code that you have. Per example there are somethings that you dont´t have defined such as mind_df, ngram_range, clf and the class imports

Comment: [link](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2019/04/predicting-movie-genres-nlp-multi-label-classification/), This code has assisted me a lot, my model is working fine, The only problem I am facing is that after I pickle the model and try to use it again, I get the error I have mentioned in the question above. I only want to know, how "" multilabel_binarizer.inverse_transform() "" function will work after pickling the model. May be I am not able to pickle this funtion. Apart from this there is no other problem. @CarlosMougan .

Comment: why dont you perform the Multilabel inside the pipeline? It has a transformer implementation.

Comment: In the pipeline, I have vectorizer and my model (clf), and when I fit my pipeline, I am using xtrain and ytrain both for fitting. But in case of multilabel binarizer, it takes labels(ytrain) ONLY for fit and transform. So there it throws the error. @CarlosMougan

Comment: Have you tried One Hot Encoder instead of multilabel binarizer?

Comment: And I dont know which classifier are you using but some of them support multiclassification so you would avoid this part.  Logistic Regression of sklearn supports multiclass

Comment: No, can you help me by sharing some good content which can be useful in my case? @CarlosMougan

Comment: What happens if you take out this lines: "mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
multilabel_y = mlb.fit_transform(y)" and call p.fit(X, y)??

Comment: I have used onevsrest model using logistic regression. @CarlosMougan

Comment: If you take out those lines? Does it give you an error? The sklearn.LogisticRegression will do multiclassication for you.

Comment: NO, there are no errors, thank you so much Sir, I was stuck in this part for more than 3 days. But now it is all good. And all thanks to you. Logistic regression did multiclassification for me. I cannot stop thanking you. @CarlosMougan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will work. Just let `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression` handle the multiclassification for you.

````py
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

X = ["How to join amazon company ","How to join google ",'Stay home']
y = ["Career Advice", "Fresher",'Other' ]

# Perform multi-label classification on class labels.

clf = LogisticRegression()

p = Pipeline([
('vect', CountVectorizer()),
('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(clf))
])

# Use multilabel classes to fit the pipeline.
p.fit(X, y);
p.predict(X)
```
````